# Callback for Token when using Google oAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-openid

For your reference, i have been doing the background reading and learning using the following links

- [Using oAuth2](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent.html)
- [Google API Developer Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#auth)
- [Understanding oAuth 2.0](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRNg4tDtrkE)

As i didnt have much success with the Google API code samples, i used the following library as an oAuth 2.0 Library

[go2.js](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud/blob/master/go2.js)

However, i am struggling to understand what is it that i am supposed to provide to the go2.getToken command in terms of callback variable.
Additionally, i used the following code to do a test POST to the Calendar and got an "unexpected end of input" javascript error.

```
<title>oauth2 connection</title>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script src="go2.js"></script>

<script>
var redirect_uri = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' ;
GO2.init(client_id, scope, redirect_uri)

POST /calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/quickAdd?text="Appointment at Somewhere on November 18th 10am-10:25am"`
```

Note: My client Id and Scope are stored in my config.js file

Answer (score 1):

The callback is going to be the function that you define which your OAuth implementation will call and pass the returned access token. You can then take the access token and continue running with that.

In 1.0a, the next step would be to have the user validate your application and then exchange the access token for a valid Authorized token. Your app will then be able to access protected data. In 2.0, from what I've been reading, the route may be a bit different, but that doesn't change the function of the callback.